# Convert batch to VBS script

Tags: windows, cmd, vbscript

I am running this command remotely in a VBS script file. The problem I am having is that it generates a CMD window momentarily and it distracts some users. How can I run this without generating the CMD window? Preferably, I want to get the WMI data in native VBS language without using oShell.run? I rather not use CMD. Thanks.

`oShell.run "cmd /c wmic logicaldisk get name,providername,description,volumename,filesystem /format:list > c:\users\%username%\drives.txt"`

Comment: [stackoverflow://\[vbscript\]+wmi+query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvbscript%5D+wmi+query)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use what you've already got and pass the 'hidden window' parameter to the Run command (see the second parameter of 0 below):

```
Dim objShell : Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cmd /c wmic logicaldisk get name,providername,description,volumename,filesystem /format:list > c:\users\%username%\drives.txt", 0, true
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try for this code in pure vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Ws,ReportFile,strHomeFolder
Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = Ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")
ReportFile = strHomeFolder & "\drives.txt"
'MsgBox GetDrives_Information
Call WriteReport(GetDrives_Information,ReportFile)
'-------------------------------------------------------
Function GetDrives_Information()
Dim oFSO,report,objWMIService,objLogicalDisk
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oDrives
Set oDrives = oFSO.Drives
Dim oDrive
Dim strLectType
on error resume next 
For Each oDrive in oDrives
        If oDrive.IsReady Then
                Select Case oDrive.DriveType
                        Case 0: strLectType = "Unknown"
                        Case 1: strLectType = "Amovible (USB)"
                        Case 2: strLectType = "Fixe (Hard Drive)"
                        Case 3: strLectType = "Network"
                        Case 4: strLectType = "CD-Rom"
                        Case 5: strLectType = "Virtuel"
                End Select
                report = report & "- Drive letter: " & oDrive.DriveLetter & vbCrLf
                report = report & "- serial number: " & oDrive.SerialNumber & vbCrLf
                report = report & "- Drive Type: " & oDrive.strLectType & vbCrLf
                If (oDrive.FileSystem <> "") Then
                        report = report & "- File system used : " & oDrive.FileSystem & vbCrLf
                End If

                Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
                Set objLogicalDisk = objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='" & oDrive.DriveLetter & ":'")
                report = report & "- There is " & objLogicalDisk.FreeSpace /1024\1024+1 & " Mo remaining space on this drive / disk" & vbCrLf
                report = report & "- There is " & objLogicalDisk.Size /1024\1024+1 & " Mo total space on this drive / disk" & vbCrLf

        End If
        report = report & vbCrLf
Next
GetDrives_Information = report
End Function
'-------------------------------------------------------
Sub WriteReport(strText,ReportFile)
    Dim fs,ts 
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(ReportFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------
```